# PHP Sentence case a string with capitalized proper nouns using a known words dictionary?

Tags: php, regex, string, fopen, fgets

#### I need to search a string of words against a dictionary of words(txt file) and capitalize any word that is not found.

I'm trying to split the string into an array of words and check them against the unix /usr/dict/words dictionary.  If a match is found for the word it gets `lcfirst($word)` if no match then `ucfirst( $word )`

The dictionary is opened and put into an array using fgetcsv (I also tried using fgets and exploding on end of line).

```
function wnd_title_case( $string ) {
$file = fopen( "/users/chris/sites/wp-dev/trunk/core/words.txt", "rb" );
while ( !feof( $file ) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv( $file );
     $exceptions = array( $line_of_text );
}


fclose( $file );
    $delimiters = array(" ", "-", "O'");
         foreach ( $delimiters as $delimiter ) {
            $words = explode( $delimiter, $string );
            $newwords = array();
                 foreach ($words as $word) {
                if ( in_array( strtoupper( $word ), $exceptions ) ) {
           // check exceptions list for any words that should be lower case
            $word = lcfirst( $word );
            } elseif ( !in_array( $word, $exceptions ) ) {
       // everything else capitalized
            $word = ucfirst( $word );
         }
       array_push( $newwords, $word );
       }
    $string = join( $delimiter, $newwords );
   }
        $string = ucfirst( $string );
   return $string;
}
```

I have verified that the file gets opened.

**The desired output:** Sentence case title string with proper nouns capitalized.
**The current output:** Title string with every word capitalized

### Edit:

Using Jay's answer below I came up with a workable solution. My first problem was that my words dictionary contained both capitalized and non capitalized words so I found a proper names dictionary to to check against using a regex callback.  It's not perfect but gets it right most of the time.

```
function title_case( $string ) {
    $fp = @fopen( THEME_DIR. "/_/inc/propernames", "r" );  
        $exceptions = array();
        if ( $fp ) {

            while( !feof($fp) ) {
                    $buffer = fgets( $fp );
                array_push( $exceptions, trim($buffer) );
            }

        }

    fclose( $fp );

    $content = strtolower( $string );
    $pattern = '~\b' . implode ( '|', $exceptions ) . '\b~i';
    $content =  preg_replace_callback (  $pattern, 'regex_callback', $content  );
    $new_content =  $content;

    return ucfirst( $new_content );
}

    function regex_callback ( $data ) {
        if ( strlen( $data[0] )  > 3 )
        return ucfirst( strtolower( $data[0] ));
        else return ( $data[0] );

    }
```

Comment: `exceptions` keeps getting overridden, so it will only have the last line.  Not sure if that's the problem (or only problem), though

Comment: Of course it's not possible to get 100% accuracy with this approach; too many proper nouns are also ordinary nouns (Nick, Polish, ...).

Comment: I think you've got multiple problems and you should ask your question about one problem only to get better answers. Isolate your problems and then fix one after the other.

Comment: Instead of exploding out your string and looping for each word, why not just do a preg_replace or str_replace on the string as whole?

Comment: /usr/dict/words includes some capitalized pronouns, IIRC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this with regex is to do the following

1. convert your text to all uppercase first letters `$content = ucwords($original_content);`
2. Using your array of words in the dictionary, create a regex by imploding all your words with a pipe character `|`, and surrounding it with boundary markers and delimiters followed by the case insensitive flag, so you would end up with `~\bword1|word2|word3\b~i` (obviously with your large list)
3. create a function to lower the matched value using strtolower to be used with preg_replace_callback

An example of a working demo is this

```
function regex_callback($data) {
    return strtolower($data[0]);
}

$original_content = 'hello my name is jay gilford';
$words = array('hello', 'my', 'name', 'is');

$content = ucwords($original_content);
$pattern = '~\b' . implode('|', $words) . '\b~i';

$content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'regex_callback', $content);

echo $content;
```

You could also optionally use strtolower to begin with on the content for consistency. The above code outputs `hello my name is Jay Gilford`